# Angular Firestore - How do I parse id of a document to another component?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am not sure how to achieve this and hope someone can help out.

I am pulling data from Firestore in an Angular app and displaying the data in a list. I'm able to get the document id no problems.

I'd like to display the record in either a modal or another component for updating/adding to with a (click)='getAnimalDetail(animal.id)' call. Just not sure how to parse the document id to the next component so I can retrieve it's fields from the database.

```
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // get the current user    
        this.curUser = user.uid;
        // console.log('Current User: ', this.curUser);
        // Specify the Collection
        this.animalCol = this.afs.collection(`users/${this.curUser}/animals/`);

        // Now generate the readable data
        this.animals = this.animalCol.snapshotChanges()
                                        .map(actions => {
                                          return actions.map(a => {
                                          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Animal;
                                          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                                          return { id, data };
  })
    })
      } else {
          console.log('Something went wrong.')

      }
    })
  }
  getAnimalDetail(animID) {
    console.log('Selected Animal: ' + animID);
    this.animDoc = this.afs.doc(`users/${this.curUser}/animals/` + animID)

    this.anim = this.animDoc.valueChanges();

  }
```

This code lists the appropriate records. Next to edit a record, I need to parse the doc ID to a function or component in order to extract the doc from the collection. Ideally, open the record in a new component is preferred or a modal and not edited inline due to other features to be implemented.

Thanks loads!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

OK,
Figured out...

Add a route in app-routing module:

```
{ path: 'animal-detail/:id', component: DetailAnimalComponent }
```

Then on the sending component:

```
    <ul *ngFor='let animal of animals | async'>
    <li routerLink="/animal-detail/{{animal.id}}"><strong>Name: {{ animal.data.name }}</strong>
...
```

and finally included in the receiving component:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

and...

```
    constructor(
    ...,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    const id: string = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log('Animal ID form URL: ', id)
   }
```

I can now use the id to get the doc from firestore.
Hope this helps someone too.

Michael